# how do I launch the crystal reports viewer from VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have installed the CR_for_VS_13_0_4.exe program that is linked to in all of these posts, but I don't know what code to use to actually launch a ".rpt" file. I am using:

```
process.start("myfile.rpt")
```

but it launches the report designer, not the viewer. How can I make sure it launches the viewer on my clients that run my app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By starting a process with `myfile.rpt`, you are telling Windows to open the file using the program associated with `.rpt` files: on your machine this is likely the CR designer; on users' machines, there is likely no program associated with `.rpt` files.

Instead of "launching" `myfile.rpt`, I think what you rather need to do (although it has been a while since I have used CR with .NET) is instantiate a CR viewer object with the report it should display set to `myfile.rpt`.

Consider a [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4533291/1810429) on using the CR viewer in VS 2010.

**UPDATE:**

With respect to your comment that you are writing code for everything rather than using the VS toolbox, I downloaded and tinkered a bit with [CR for VS 2010](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824) to successfully PoC the following for you:

[image: PoC Project in VS 2010 Solution Explorer]

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // the CR viewer
        private CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer crystalReportViewer1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // 
            // crystalReportViewer1
            // 
            this.crystalReportViewer1 = new CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer();

            // FORNOW: just some "who cares" setup assignments for PoC - to be adjusted of course
            this.crystalReportViewer1.ActiveViewIndex = -1;
            this.crystalReportViewer1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.crystalReportViewer1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
            this.crystalReportViewer1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.crystalReportViewer1.Name = "crystalReportViewer1";
            this.crystalReportViewer1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 150);
            this.crystalReportViewer1.TabIndex = 3;

            // FORNOW: a DataSet1 as a dummy data source for PoC - really to be loaded with meaningful data of course
            DataSet1 ds1 = new DataSet1();
            ds1.Tables["DataTable1"].Rows.Add(new object[] { 25 }); // whatever - just some data for PoC

            // the CR document - myfile.rpt
            ReportDocument reportDocument1 = new ReportDocument();
            reportDocument1.Load("myfile.rpt");
            // See the note regarding the next statement that follows the code.
            reportDocument1.SetDataSource(ds1); // set to use our dummy data source for PoC

            // the CR viewer set to use the CR document
            this.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument1;

            // the CR viewer added to the form's controls
            this.Controls.Add(this.crystalReportViewer1);

            // etcetera
        }

        // etcetera
    }
}
```

If you are targeting .NET 4.0, you will encounter a `FileNotFoundException` regarding `crdb_adoplus.dll` at `reportDocument1.SetDataSource(ds1);` unless you add the following to your `app.config`:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

See [SAP Note 1525432 - Could not load file or assembly 'file:///crdb_adoplus.dll' or one of its dependencies](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/servlet/prt/portal/prtroot/com.sap.km.cm.docs/oss_notes_boj/sdn_oss_boj_bi/sap%28bD1lbiZjPTAwMQ==%29/bc/bsp/spn/scn_bosap/notes%7B6163636573733d36393736354636443646363436353344333933393338323636393736354637333631373036453646373436353733354636453735364436323635373233443330333033303331333533323335333433333332%7D.do) for more information.

On a final note, although this *can* be done without the VS toolbox, I would highly recommend using it to put a lot of design-time code for the CR viewer in your form's `.designer.cs` file and focus your form's `.cs` file on the more meaningful code you need to write to present the report.  TIMTOWDI, though.

Happy reporting!

Comment: I'm not using the toolbox to add items to my project. Everything I do is code based. The link only talks about using the toolbox. How do I use the viewer from code?

Comment: The idea is the same, the toolbox just being a drag-and-drop way to instantiate a viewer control and add it to the form's controls.  I will update my answer with a bit of code that shows the direction I think you need to go.

Comment: @user2721815, I added an update with a PoC code sample as promised.

Comment: BTW, this led to quite an [installation adventure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21313257/1810429) that fit [another SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8298835/1810429), @user2721815! :)